# Look up service implementations dynamically

Tags: angular, factory, strategy-pattern

Our Angular application has a service which can have different implementations, aka. “strategies”. For simplicity, let’s assume it’s an “event reporting” service. The event reporting service has a function for reporting information. Depending on a runtime preference, the reporting can either turned off, go to the `console`, or be sent to a REST API, or go somewhere else.

Using pure TS, this would look like:

```js
interface IReporter {
  report (message: string): void;
}

class NoReporter implements IReporter {
  report (message: string): void {
    // no op.
  }
}

class ConsoleReporter implements IReporter {
  report (message: string): void {
    console.log(message);
  }
}

// etc.
```

In a consumer, I’d put some factory which delivers the desired reporter, e.g. based on a user-preference setting:

```js
getReporter (key: string): IReporter {
  switch (key) {
    // … tedious cases, which need to be mainted. Yikes!
  }
}
```

However, this feels not very “Angular”-like. First step would probably be to make proper Angular services of the individual reporters, but this alone feels like little gained. So: Is there some existing mechanism which would give me above factory functionality to dynamically look up an implementation? Any patterns, example or best practices to follow?

Comment: Angulars DI system provides [FactoryProviders ](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers)
This should perfectly solve your problem.

Comment: @MaxK Perfect. Many thanks for the pointer! (feel free to post this as “proper” answer and you’ll get my upvote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comment [FactoryProviders](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers) perfectly solve this problem.

You have to define your `IReporter` interface as an [class interface](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#class-interface) because interfaces don't exist at runtime and therefore they are no valid DI tokens:

```
export abstract class IReporter {
  report: (message: string) => void;
}

@Injectable()
export class NoReporter implements IReporter{
  report(message:string):void{

  }
}

@Injectable()
export class ConsoleReporter implements IReporter {
  report(message: string): void {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

Now you could create your `reporterFactory` and `reporterProvider` like shown below:

```
const reporterFactory = (key: string) => {
  switch (key) {
    case 'no-report':
      return () => new NoReporter();
    case 'console-report':
      return () => new ConsoleReporter();
    default:
      return () => new ConsoleReporter();
  }
};

export const reporterProvider = (key: string) => {
  return {
    provide: IReporter,
    useFactory: reporterFactory(key)
  }
};
```

And inject a reporter in your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `TESTCOMPONENT`,
  providers: [
    reporterProvider('console-report')
  ]
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor(private reporter: IReporter) {
    reporter.report('it works!!!');
  }

}
```